# A new Thread should be created on ServiceMain?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-services

The MSDN says that:

"The ServiceMain function should create a global event, call the RegisterWaitForSingleObject    function on this event, and exit. This will terminate the thread that is running the ServiceMain function, but will not terminate the service..."

So the question is: A new Thread should be created inside the ServiceMain function to execute the service code, or I can simple set the service to RUNNING state and uses the ServiceMain thread to run the service code? If the ServiceMain thread is used to run the service code the SCM will remain locked, even if the service state is set to RUNNING?

Answer (score 3):

I do not think the way of implementing services described by that statement from MSDN is the only possible way. That would contradict MSDN service example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb540476(v=vs.85).aspx . In the example the service waits for events in the same thread that called ServiceMain. This way is probably better for simple services that work just fine with a single thread.

If you choose to use RegisterWaitForSingleObject way you do not have to create threads explicitly. MSDN page for RegisterWaitForSingleObject says: "New wait threads are created automatically when required." You do have to open I/O channels you service is going to monitor and bind their handles to thread pool before exiting ServiceMain.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685138%28VS.85%29.aspx): "The Service Control Manager (SCM) waits until the service reports a status of `SERVICE_RUNNING`. It is recommended that the service reports this status as quickly as possible, as other components in the system that require interaction with SCM will be blocked during this time."

The control dispatcher creates a new thread to execute the ServiceMain function for the service. The ServiceMain function should perform the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685984%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) tasks.

> 5..  Perform the service tasks, or, if there are no pending tasks, return control to the caller. Any change in the service state warrants
>   a call to `SetServiceStatus` to report new status information.

From [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687414%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example follow that you can perform more complex initialization tasks inside the ServiceMain function such as creating additional threads.

Guidance for creating [Multithreaded Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).